# Display nav bar on multiple pages

Tags: javascript, jquery, menu

I have a submenu that I only want to show when the parent or parent subpages are active. I would like my script to work with more than one URL.

The code I have working for a single page is:

```
var myurl = "http://localhost/wordpress/?page_id=36"; 
var currenturl = window.location; 
if(myurl != currenturl) { 
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#main_nav ul.sub-menu').css({display: "none"}); 
    });
}
```

I tried using the code again with different variable names for additional URLs but no luck. I can't seem to find how to create a URL array or if I can even do this at all.

Answer (score 0):

The below should do what you want:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var urls = ["/wordpress/?page_id=36", "/wordpress/?page_id=37"];
    var currenturl = window.location.pathname + window.location.search;
    if($.inArray(currenturl, urls) == -1) { 
        $('#main_nav ul.sub-menu').hide();
    }​
});
```

As you'll see, I've used `http://localhost/wordpress/?page_id=37` as an example second URL that you want to display the sub navigation on.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer but it didn't work...the menu is not HIDING at all...

Comment: Scrooby, thanks...I did put in my own URLs but the menu is still visible on all pages...

Comment: Hmm, if you do `alert(current url);` what value do you get?

Comment: ...all I get is an error...what is "current url"?...so I assumed you meant to use it without the space...meaning "currenturl" which is the var name...and even that, there was NO alert at all

Comment: Sorry, yes I meant currenturl as one word. I've updated my code in my original answer. If you try that, you should at least get the alert popping up.

Comment: Scrooby, I get the directory name "/wordpress/" and I'm using the FULL URL not just the "wordpress/?page_id=36"

Comment: I've updated my code again to include the query string parameters. You'll need to use the "/wordpress/?page_id=36" rather than the full url the code to work. I didn't use the full url to reduce duplication.

Comment: Scrooby...we're getting there...now it's working perfectly...but the opposite of what I want...where I want it show, it hides...and thanks for your help and patients...

Comment: So close :) I've updated the code once again, it's just a case of replacing `>= 0` with `== -1`